# Find and Uninstall Software Program In Windows 8?

Tags: windows

I am trying to Uninstall program in Windows 8. I cannot uninstall the program using the Program and Features or Uninstall program feature from Windows, because I keep getting an error message that one of the .DLL file is missing. How do you find where the program was install if you cannot find it on your C drive under the Program Files? And is there another way to search and uninstall the program manually in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you or someone using your computer must have deleted one or more files associated with the install. The best tool I've found for finding "stuff" on a hard drive can be downloaded here http://www.voidtools.com/  You can then delete everything associated with the program. It may still appear to installed, that will take a registry deletion using `regedt32.exe` and going to hKey_local_machine\software.

Comment: Do you know how to search for these programs on your hard drive manually if they are not in the C://Program Files? which other places do programs get installed?

Comment: The tool referenced above is the best search tool I've found. "Program Files" is the typical default install, although you can choose anywhere during the install step. It seems from your comment that somebody may have deleted the entire program (instead of uninstalling). If you can't find a trace of it then simply go to the registry and delete it's remains. An alternative is to reinstall and select the "repair" option if it has one then uninstall cleanly.